# javascript swap and replace string

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript, I have a string like `substringof('para1',para2) and substringof('para3',para4) and xxx and xxx or other strings` and I want to convert it to `contains(para2,'para1') and contains(para4,'para3')`

so, what I need to do is to swap the 2 parameters inside `substringof` and then replace the `substringof` with `contains`

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
string.replace(/substringof\(([^,]+),([^)]+)/, "substringof($2,$1");
```

- `([^,]+)` Matches anything other than a `,` captures in group 1, `$1`. This matches the first parameter.
- `([^)]+)` Matches anything other than a `)` , captures in group 2, `$2`. This part matches the second parameter.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wR5oA6/1)

**Example**

```
"substringof('para1',para2)".replace(/substringof\(([^,]+),([^)]+)/, "substringof($2,$1"));
// Outputs
// => substringof(para2,'para1')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do. Hope it helps.

```
var str = "substringof('para1',para2) and substringof('para3',para4)";    
var replacedStr = str.replace(/substringof\(([^,]+),([^)]+)/g, "contains($2,$1");
```

Comment: It will do the swipe and replace for all the occurences in the string.